# PE Puppet Console and manage multiple node user accounts

Tags: class, console, puppet, accounts, puppet-enterprise

I'm new to puppet and using Puppet Enterprise with the module from puppet for accounts. https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/accounts

I'd like to be able to manage the user account details from the PE console for multiple users.

The best I can seem to get to is managing them within

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
```

Which contains:

```
node default {

accounts::user { 'jeff':
  comment  => 'Jeff McCune',
  groups   => [
    'wheel',
  ],
  locked   => true,
  sshkeys  => [
    'ssh-rsa AAAA...',
    'ssh-dss AAAA...',
  ],
  password => '!!',
  ensure => 'present',
}

accounts::user { 'dave':
  comment  => 'Dave Smith',
  groups   => [
    'wheel',
  ],
  locked   => true,
  sshkeys  => [
    'ssh-rsa AAAA...',
    'ssh-dss AAAA...',
  ],
  password => '!!',
  ensure => 'present',
}

}
```

I'd ideally I'd like to be able to manage them per PE classification within the console. So each users details can be parameters I enter in the PE console - the number of users would vary, but just need the principle to able to add more than one.

I've tried adding into a manifest but struggled with declaring more than one account. I did that by:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/my_app/manifests/init.pp
```

which contained:

```
class my_app (

$username => '',
$usercomment => '',
$sshkey ='',

){

accounts::user { $username:
  comment  => $usercomment,
  groups   => [
    'sudonopw',
  ],
  locked   => false,
  sshkeys  => [
   $sshkey,
  ],
  password => '!!',
  ensure => present, 

}

}
```

This allowed me to apply this class to any variation of my node classification and allow me to manage those parameters in the PE console. However I couldn't add more than one account to each node, as the class had been declared.

Can anyone give me some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: It kind of sounds like you are trying to do this: https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/rbac_intro.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. It's not the puppet pe console I want to manage access to. Rbac is about access to that interface. It's user accounts on the agent servers I'm looking to manage.

Comment: Oh, got it. I think you need to learn the Puppet DSL and code/data then. You can easily manage user accounts with Puppet after learning that.

Comment: That's why I've ended up here as my DSL above only allows me to create a single user account if I'm pulling the parameters declared in the pe console. I'll keep on searching as I must me missing something obvious.